# extern variable in namespace c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, global-variables, extern

I have a question about the extern variable in namespace c++. Here is the .h file of the CBVR class

```
namespace parameters
{
class CBVR 
{
private:

    std::string database;

public:

    CBVR(void);

    void initialize(const std::string &fileName);
    static void printParameter(const std::string &name,
                               const std::string &value);
};
extern CBVR cbvr;
}
```

The .cpp file looks like:

```
parameters::CBVR parameters::cbvr;


using namespace xercesc;

parameters::CBVR::CBVR(void)
{

}

void parameters::CBVR::initialize(const std::string &_fileName)
{

}

void parameters::CBVR::printParameter(const std::string &_name, const std::string &_value)
{
    if (_value.empty())
    {
        cbvr << "  -> " << _name << " = < EMPTY!!! >" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cbvr << "  -> " << _name << " = \"" << _value << "\"" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In the method `printParameter`, we're using `cbvr` without any reference to the namespace. `parameters::CBVR parameters::cbvr;` handles it but I don't understand what it means and why it allows the `cbvr` variable to be used like this in the class?

EDITED:

I did this but it says:  `error: undefined reference to parameters::cbvr`

```
//parameters::CBVR parameters::cbvr;
using namespace parameters;
using namespace xercesc;

CBVR::CBVR(void)
{

}

void CBVR::initialize(const std::string &_fileName)
{

}

void CBVR::printParameter(const std::string &_name, const std::string &_value)
{
    if (_value.empty())
    {
        cbvr << "  -> " << _name << " = < EMPTY!!! >" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cbvr << "  -> " << _name << " = \"" << _value << "\"" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

so what's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the member function's definition, you're in the scope of the class, which is in turn in the scope of its surrounding namespace. So anything declared in the class or the namespace can be accessed without qualification there.

Outside the namespace, the unqualified names aren't available, which is why you need the `parameters::` qualification in the variable and function definitions.

Comment: @Maystro: You commented out the definition of `cvbr`, so the linker complained that it wasn't defined. Why would you do that?

Comment: I just want to understand the difference and what it does exactly "parameters::CBVR parameters::cbvr"? you said the definition? it was already defined in the namespace, was not?

Comment: @Maystro: No, it was declared (not defined) in the header - that's what the `extern` means. The declaration states that it exists, but doesn't allocate any storage for it. It must also be defined, in just one source file, to be usable. That's what the first line of your original source file did, which you commented out in the update.

Answer (score 1):

Having

```
void parameters::CBVR::printParameter(const std::string &_name, const std::string &_value)
{
    ...    }
```

is same as

```
namespace parameters
{// notice, the signature of the method has no "parameters" before CBVR
    void CBVR::printParameter(const std::string &_name, const std::string &_value)
    {
        ...    }
}
```

The class is in the scope of the namespace, so the body of the class you are implementing is in the scope as well.